# One url with two different paths (url rewriting)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url as following

```
http://example.com/post/post-title/1
```

so it is /file-name/post-name/page-number

so i want the 1st page to display without page number.

```
http://example.com/post/post-title
```

and then from second page

```
http://example.com/post/post-title/2
```

My htaccess code is.

```
RewriteRule post/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ post.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Is there any way to do this? Applicate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2 rules for this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# default rule for page #1
RewriteRule post/([\w-]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&page=1 [NC,L,QSA]

# to handle URLs with specific page #
RewriteRule post/([\w-]+)/(\d+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```